# Sending data from notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have to send data from my notification without starting any activity. I searched it and found that the way to do so was via broadcast receiver. I implemented it , however the broadcast receiver is not being started. Can anyone find the problem?

Here is the broadcast receiver

```
public class AttendanceStorage extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
}
}
```

Here is the intent I am sending data through

```
Intent intent11=new Intent(context,AttendanceStorage.class);
                intent11.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent11.setAction(""+subject+" Yes");
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,num,intent11,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I also registered the receiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AttendanceStorage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest.xml, you have to register your receiver to the action you want to

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AttendanceStorage">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="my_custom_action" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When creating the `Intent`, you can just use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my_custom_action");
```

And that's all. You can pass data through the `Intent` by putting an extra and getting it in your receiver.